# How can I draw a rotated UIView with a shadow but without the shadow being rotated as well

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, shadow

I'd like the shadow applied correctly after rotation. This is my code:

```
myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 180.0 * 90.0);

myButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(12.0, 12.0);
myButton.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
myButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
myButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

Without rotation the shadow looks fine:

[image]

But after rorating it by 90° the shadow is rotated as well:

[image]

Is there anything I can do about it without overriding the drawRect method and do low level drawing? Or maybe some method which corrects the shadowOffset with a given rotation angle? It's easy to correct the offset by hand for 90° so this is no option ;)

It should look like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

**With help of Bartosz Ciechanowski this works now!**

```
float angleInRadians = M_PI / 180.0 * -35.0;

myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleInRadians);

myButton.layer.shadowOffset = [self correctedShadowOffsetForRotatedViewWithAngle:(angleInRadians) 
                                                          andInitialShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(12.0, 12.0)];
myButton.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
myButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
myButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

This results in:

[image]

instead of

[image]

Comment: I didn't get whether hand-correction of the offset is an acceptable solution for you or not. You can compute the offset either manually with sin/cos or just apply an inverted transform of the button

Comment: @Gobara, hand-correction is absolutely acceptable but it has to be a reusable solution not just one for my code example. A method with this header would be pretty cool: `- (CGSize)correctedShadowOffsetForRotatedViewWithAngle:(float)anAngle andInitialShadowOffset:(CGSize)anOffset`

Comment: have you tried using any of `UIView`'s `convert...` methods?  It looks like you'd have to put the `CGSize` in a rect because UIView doesn't have a method for converting sizes directly.

Comment: @Richard, I don't know how. If you have an example, I'd be thankful to try.

Comment: Remove the shadow before rotation and then apply it again?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming `anAngle` is in radians:

```
- (CGSize)correctedShadowOffsetForRotatedViewWithAngle:(CGFloat)anAngle 
                                andInitialShadowOffset:(CGSize)anOffset
{
    CGFloat x = anOffset.height*sinf(anAngle) + anOffset.width*cosf(anAngle);
    CGFloat y = anOffset.height*cosf(anAngle) - anOffset.width*sinf(anAngle);

    return CGSizeMake(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great. I'll update my answer to show the result. Bounty comes in 22h :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try using

```
myButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-12.0, -12.0);
```

**to**

```
myButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(12.0, 12.0);
```

Just try using this, if it works.Either you need to set the shadow with Trial & Error method.
This is just a suggestion or a trick if could solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry but as I mentioned in my question: correction by hand is no option. But thank for your effort.