# Animate CAShapeLayer & Shadow independently

Tags: ios, swift3, core-animation, cashapelayer, caanimation

I have a 'UIView' Subclass called 'HexagonView' in which I create a layer to display a Hexagon. I then add another layer with the same path as shadow layer. I had to do it this way since I could not display a shadow outside of the 'layer.mask' Shape. 
My goal is to animate a 360° rotation of the shape, while the shadow stays on it's position instead of moving around with the rotation.

See example image

[image: Animated Hexagon]

This is the code I have so far:

```
@IBDesignable class HexagonView: UIView {

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
{

    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

    configureLayer()

    addShadow()

}

override init(frame: CGRect)
{

    super.init(frame: frame)

    configureLayer()

    addShadow()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    configureLayer()

    addShadow()

}

func configureLayer()
{

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

    maskLayer.frame = bounds

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size)

    maskLayer.path = getHexagonPath().cgPath

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    layer.addSublayer(maskLayer)

}

private func getHexagonPath() -> UIBezierPath
{

    let width = frame.size.width

    let height = frame.size.height

    let padding = width * 1 / 8 / 2

    let path = UIBezierPath()

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: 0))

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - padding, y: height / 4))

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - padding, y: height * 3 / 4))

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: height))

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: padding, y: height * 3 / 4))

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: padding, y: height / 4))

    path.close()

    return path

}

func addShadow()
{

    let s = CAShapeLayer()
    s.fillColor = backgroundColor?.cgColor
    s.frame = layer.bounds
    s.path = getHexagonPath().cgPath

    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    layer.addSublayer(s)

    layer.masksToBounds = false

    layer.shadowColor = AppAppearance.Colors.labelBackground.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 10)
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.shadowPath = getHexagonPath().cgPath
    layer.shadowRadius = 0

}


func rotate(duration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil)
{

    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0)
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration
    rotateAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)


    if let delegate = completionDelegate as? CAAnimationDelegate {
        rotateAnimation.delegate = delegate
    }

    layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)

}
}
```

How can I achieve the shadow rotation on its starting position rather than having it attached to the white layer.

Comment: Maybe add another hexagon view below this white hexagon, and add background colour so it looks like shadow, and then rotate both views...

Comment: I can give that a try, but that would mean I always will have 2 calls for everything. And also I need to implement a blur function for the shadowRadius

Comment: Just wrap it in some parent view and then you will need to make just one call.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Are you trying to make it like the gif, or keep the shadow where it should be naturally (always below the hex), but rotating to match?

Comment: I want it to behave naturally and not like in the gif

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I draw a rotated UIView with a shadow but without the shadow being rotated as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777917/how-can-i-draw-a-rotated-uiview-with-a-shadow-but-without-the-shadow-being-rotat)

Comment: The above answer helps a lot for static rotations but it gets much tricker for animation. You say you don't want multiple calls.. I'd just combine them under one parent function, but still use multiple layers with ONE animation applied to them. just apply the same animation to both layers. You'll have simpler code and the correct result.

Comment: The problem with the same animation for 2 layers is, that the delegate gets called twice as well. My current solution with 2 layers is wether to have 2 different animation that are essentially the same but one has a delegate and the other not, or have my whole delegate in an if statement that checks which of the layers just called the animation. Both of them are not ideal IMO. If there is no other way, then I go with one of those solutions though.

Comment: Makes sense. It would be great if shadows behaved correctly. I'd think that would be the more common need.

Comment: Well one can use light physics and simulate a light source :) I see if I can post my solution later on

Comment: I would be interested to see a working example solution to this if anyone has one to share